# Wasm-function memory access out of bounds in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After developing my application for a while, i always get this error and always have to delete the node modules and run the npm install again to clear the error. i am not sure what is causing this error.

The error:

```
./src/components/admin/personal_request/personal_request.jsx
RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[18]:0x1d4f
    at allocate_mappings (<anonymous>:wasm-function[27]:0x33f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue when using wasm. The problem seems to be when a wasm function throws. In my case I was validating something like this:

```
try {
 wasm.callFn(...args)
 return true
} catch(e) {
 return false
}
```

I don't really see that much into it but this [link](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1963) and the issues linked there should give you an insight. AFAIK, when a wasm function throws, the destructor is not called which pollutes the memory, making it smaller and smaller until it runs out and then you access memory out of bounds.

In my case, I solved this by replacing the wasm functionality with another lib.